# How to Remove those keywords that not belongs to City from a Dictionary in python Text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have `Dictionary.txt` City names dictionary file and match the city name in CSV file and count the number of Matches in every row.

I have a problem with `Dictionary.txt` file,it have some keywords which do not belongs to the cities name. so I want to remove all of these irrelevant keywords from dictionary file. I have no Idea that how to solve it.

**For Example some Keywords of Dictionary.txt are:**

```
Nowy Dworek
Dar Bel Amri
Abaren
Hassi blal
Ambodivona
Chakla
Ippatam
Suti
Via
Zingeyskiy
Luesslingen
Bolshaya Markha
Ard Na Greine
Raskhovets
Ksizovo
Rock Elm
Batnahit
```

In this file, I have many Irrelevant keywords e.g, in a given sample `via` keywords do not belong to the cities, same as my output result are given below you can see there are many irrelevant keywords which are matches in the description,

```
Sr_Num |    Description Cities  |matched Keywords    |Cities Total matches
1      | any description........|temple , via , Thai |3
2                                last , canada , give , on| 4
3                                this , is , on , louis |4
4                                Ocean , I , US , a , is , Southern , huge , of , this , War|   10
5                                queen  |1
6                                But , is , me , cole|  4
7                                all , Lester , Mason , is , on , us , long , of|   8
8                                Wallach , Bad , Good , Sanchez |4
```

**So, What is the Solution to remove all irrelevant keywords from `dictionary.txt` file which not belongs to cities name ???**

Comment: Do you want us to make code for you or give you the path to resolve it yourself ?

Comment: @Nenri   If you can also provide a solution with code then it will be better then just direction or path to solve the problem because I am not so good in programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not provide code because i think you can do it yourself, but here is how I'd do it :

First, split your `Dictionary.txt` to get all words into a list.

Then, split your CSV file to get every City Name into a list.

Then, loop through this last list to check if it is a word from your dictionnary list, and if not, remove it from the list.

Finally, rewrite you CSV out of the final list you get.

EDIT : Here's some code to show you :

```py
yourDictionnary = open('Dictionary.txt', 'r').read().splitlines() #this puts contents from the dictionnary into a list line by line
theCsvContent = ','.join(open('csvName.csv', 'r').read().splitlines()).split(',') #this puts contents from the csv into a list element by element

for index, word in enumerate(theCsvContent): #loops through theCsv with index as the word index and word as the word we're iterating on
    if word not in yourDictionnary: #checks if the word is in dictionnary and if not :
        del theCsvContent[index] #removes the word from the csv

open('result.csv', 'w').write(','.join(theCsvContent)) #this writes the edited csv into result.csv
```

Comment: I have no idea that How Can I remove irrelevant keywords from `dictionary.txt` file that not belongs to city names .

Comment: @csit not from `dictionary.txt`, from the csv u're looking in

Comment: Okay Your are saying right, But if some words that are not belongs to any city names e.g. `this , is , on ,Over , Old , It , a , From etc ..... ` these are those names  which I saw In the dictionary  file ,,,,,,If these are matched in the CSV so My results will not good because these type of words are NOT belongs to any city thats why I want to remove these irrelevant keywords ,and thats why i am finding  a solution, I think now you can understand more better this issue .

Comment: @csit and my solution still works, it'll remove them. The whole purpose of what you ask and of my answer is removing all things in csv which aren't city names in `dictionary.txt`

Comment: Edited with some example code. (remember that you'll have to edit it to fulfill your needs)

Comment: okay! but I don't delete the words from CSV, I want to delete those words FROM DICTIONARY FILE THAT are not Cities name and I have no idea to compare or verify the dictionary to save the city name and remove the non-city name from the dictionary. but Your idea is Good. and here is I need file  related to city names to compare my dictinary file to verify/confirm the city names and remove non-city names from dictionary file.

Comment: @csit So u should have another file where you're sure that there are only city names, and apply the same algorythm to delete non-city names from your dictionary. Or find an API on internet that tells you if a word is a city name or not and test with it